# Add numeric strings in C# and preserve formating

Tags: c#, string

I have an issue where I need to add two numeric strings "$1,234.56" and "$9,876.54" and get a string "$11,111.10"

I can convert the strings to numbers, perform the addition, but I don't know of a good way to preserve the formatting when I ToString() the result. I can add a couple of if statements along the lines: does the input have dollar sign, decimal point, percent sign and construct the format string accordingly, but this is clunky and will fail if we ever need to support more than one number format.

Does anyone know how to add numeric strings and preserve formatting?

EDIT: To answer the questions. The format of all strings being added at a given time is the same ie: I don't need to worry about adding $ and £ (in fact £ is not currently supported), However, there are several possible formats that are currently supported and more may be added in the future:

$1,234.00; $1,234; 1234; 1,234; 1,234.00; 1234%; 1,234%; 1,234.00%

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you added "$12345.56" and "£1,234,567.89"? (In other words, when the formatting isn't consistent?)

Comment: If you only support a single number format at the moment, why not just hard-code that?

Comment: Do you not know the format before hand? Or are you trying to make a function that will handle it no matter what?

Comment: Are you imagining that you might infer the number format from the inputs?

Comment: You'd need to force the format a input so you can hardcode it. For instace 9,999,999,999.9999 could be a format. Only 4 special characters to eliminate to process your string

Comment: "1,234.00%" is not a realistic numeric format, it's someone forgetting to set their Excel column formatting right. What's your input format? If it *is* Excel, any chance you could simply get the raw value of the cell, ignoring formatting?

Comment: Are you in control of how you receive the numbers? What decides what format it comes over in?

Comment: My input is not excel, but at the point I am doing the addition, I no longer have access to either the raw data, nor the format string. I need to infer the format from the numbers. Also 1,234.00% might be unrealistic data, but I still need to be able to handle it.

Comment: I'd ditch the idea of "inferring" anything and just run it through a succession of parsers (hand-written regexes, since `Int/Decimal/Double.Parse` won't handle everything you want). First one to recognize wins, is used for all the data and returns the appropriate C# format string for the end result. This always needs to come with the caveat of "if the end result is not what you expected, it's not my fault, fix your input". You can make this extensible in the sense that adding a new format should only require one new regex -> format mapping, but I wouldn't try making it fully generic.

Comment: I am not sure how reliable it is but as a starting point if you replace all numbers before the decimal point with # and all numbers after with 0 then pass this to `ToString` then that might be a good starting point. eg $1,234.00 becomes `$#,###.00` and you then do  `value.ToString("$#,###.00")`. This seems to work at a glance but it leaves edge cases unspecified. eg "$700"+"$700" could be either "$1400" or "$1,400". On the other hand it will work, it just won't add thousand separators...

Comment: Actually that will work with your currencies but not with percentages. Some messing around could get it to work probably though (eg taking the % sign off and adding it manually afterwards).

Comment: If you don't know the format and you have say `1.234` and `5,678`, how would you know if the dot is the decimal point and the comma the thousand separator or the reverse. So the answer could either be `1.239,678` or `5,678.234`. And you have the same problem if only one number have the separator. For example, if you have `1,234 + 567` the answer could be `1801` if the comma was a thousand separator or be `568,234` if it was a decimal separator. **The whole idea make no sense.** If the original program was poorly written, then fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the first numeric string as a template and create a number format from it:

```
var posshalves = firstNumericString.Split('.');
var fmthalves = new string[2] { posshalves[0], (posshalves.Length < 2 ? "" : "."+posshalves[1])};
var intfmt = Regex.Replace(fmthalves[0], @"[0-9]", "#");
intfmt = Regex.Replace(intfmt, @"#+", "#");
var decfmt = Regex.Replace(fmthalves[1], "[0-9]", "0");
var format = $"{intfmt}{decfmt}";
```